# Formulae in workflows

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to add the formulae in the workflow mentioned below:

```
AND( ISCHANGED (Account.Name),OR( ( Account.Type  =  'Client')))
```

but it shows the error as Error:

> The ISCHANGED function cannot reference the Account.Name field

Basically I trying to do here is when I change the account name field on contact and account type field on account is client,the contact owner should get an email alert.

The account name is a lookup value here. Can you suggest me a correct formulae?

Comment: Can i use here a previous value formulae. Please suggest!!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008p4SIAQ) on the Salesforce Developer Forms, you are able to use the `ISCHANGED()` formula in a workflow, only when the workflow is set to `Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited`.

You could try something like `IF((PRIORVALUE(Account.Name) == Account.Name), ..., ...)`. That may work in your context.

Comment: I have already used the condition as Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited,still I am getting the same error.Can you suggest me another formulae

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a suggestion on an alternative method.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact formulae

Comment: I try to use the AND(PRIORVALUE (Account.Name)<> Account.Name , OR( Account.Type ='Client')) but it shows the same error

Comment: Is the Account.Name value a lookup field, or is Account a lookup field? I don't believe you'll be able to check for changes on a separate object.

Comment: Yes Account Name is a lookup field and when I change this field(Account Name) on contact object,the workflow should trigger.

Comment: So you are trying to run a workflow rule when the Account is changed on a contact, or are you trying to update the contacts when the Accounts Name is changed?

Comment: Yes,I am trying to write a workflow when account type filed on contact is Client and when account name on contact object is changed,the contact owner should receive an email alert.Kindly help!!

Comment: Try removing the `.Name` section of the workflow rule, as you are trying to check a value which the workflow rule does not have access too. Your formula will likely look something like `AND(ISCHANGED(Contact.Account), Contact.Account.Type == 'Client')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the formula with 
`AND(ISCHANGED(`**`AccountId`**`), Contact.Account.Type == 'Client')`

As mentioned in the earlier post, please ensure the evaluation criteria is set to `created, and every time it’s edited`